# Keeping two fields in sync when one of them is updated

Tags: progress-4gl, openedge

The application I'm working on is a character based application. there is a field `adfc.unme-code` in a table and another field `arbu.unit-code-shu`. These two fields are shown in different windows but they must be in sync. When I update `unme-code`, `unit-code-shu` must be updated too.

Is a simple assign statement would be enough or should I do something else? Also, should I use the actual fields or a buffer?

Comment: Do you have any code to show? Have you tried something that doesn't work?

Comment: When you say that "they must be in sync" do you mean that the values in the database must be synchronized or are do you also need to visualization to be coordinated?

Comment: I have loads of code. It's a huge project. And there are lots of related files (`.edd`, `.edt`, `.i`,` .p`, `.rel`, `.tp` and so on) so I can't just share a block of code and ask. But this is the part I chose `unme-code` if I want to change it  `ELSE IF lc-last-field = "unme-code":U
THEN DO:
    IF lc-help = "CHOOSE1":U
    THEN RUN ch/unme00p.p (INPUT(INPUT x00adfc.unme-code)
                           ,OUTPUT chooseid
                          ).
END.` @Jensd

Comment: I mean when I change `unme-code`, the `unit-code-shu` must be changed and be shown with the new value in related screen, also when I write a query to the table I should see the same value. So the table fields will be updated each time. @TomBascom

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `ASSIGN` statement in your code to assign both values at the same time. If there's a possibility of some other process changing those fields, you can create a database trigger procedures on each field to copy the value over to the other field. In the Data Dictionary, view the field properties and click on the "Triggers..." button to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, `ASSIGN` is used to set the value of a buffers/records field. However: certain critera needs to be met:

- The buffer/record needs to be available.
- You must have the "lock" of the buffer/record.

If you have the record available and locked you can simply do:

```
ASSIGN arbu.unit-code-shu = adfc.unme-code.
```

To make this code "safer" you can simply make sure that `arbu` is available and not locked by any other user. And finally it will handle if your assign fails because you have no lock at all.

```
IF AVAILABLE arbu AND NOT LOCKED arbu THEN DO:
  ASSIGN arbu.unit-code-shu = adfc.unme-code NO-ERROR.
  IF ERROR-STATUS:GET-NUMBER(1) = 396 THEN DO:
    MESSAGE "Apparently the record is locked." VIEW-AS ALERT-BOX ERROR.
  END.
END.
```

If you do not have the record (or the right locking) you need to look into your application and see how you can add this feature. What identifies the right record of the second table? A single id? Something else? Are there always a 1 to 1 relation between `arbu`  and `adfc` etc?

Perhaps your application has a simple way of setting the value of a field. If there is a architecture at place you should try to stick to it...